# "Unable to find deploy strategy for module: no known mapping" / when Snowdog SASS theme / or updating any dependency

Tags: magento2, composer, sass

I have installed the

```
"snowdog/theme-blank-sass": "^0.10.1"
```

Now I am trying to replace it with our fork, versioned 0.110.1 (just added 100)

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/iMi-digital/magento2-theme-blank-sass.git"
    }
  ],
```

I am getting

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                  
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating snowdog/theme-blank-sass (0.10.1 => 0.110.1): Downloading (connectiDownloading (100%)         


  [ErrorException]                                             
  Unable to find deploy strategy for module: no known mapping
```

Edit:

Deleting the old module from the vendor folder and

```
composer require snowdog/theme-blank-sass=dev-imi-develop
```

worked...

But I can not update the module - I always have to remove the module first via `rm -rf vendor/snowdog/theme-blank-sass`

edit: full composer json

```
{
    "name": "example/example",
    "description": "Example",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.6",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "firegento/magesetup2": "dev-develop",
    "splendidinternet/mage2-locale-de-de": "^1.13",
    "snowdog/frontools": "^1.4",
    "snowdog/theme-blank-sass": "dev-imi-develop",
    "magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp": "^1.4",
    "adyen/module-payment": "^2.0",
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^5.2",
    "ves/magento2-imageslider" :"dev-patch-1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
    "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
    "magento": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "snowdog_theme_blank_sass": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/iMi-digital/magento2-theme-blank-sass"
    },
    "ves_magento2_imageslider": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/ihor-sviziev/imageslider"
    }
    },
    "extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "auto-append-gitignore": "true"
    }
}
```

Updated composer json

```
{
    "name": "example/example",
    "description": "Example",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.6",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "firegento/magesetup2": "dev-develop",
    "splendidinternet/mage2-locale-de-de": "^1.13",
    "snowdog/frontools": "^1.4",
    "snowdog/theme-blank-sass": "dev-imi-develop",
    "magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp": "^1.4",
    "adyen/module-payment": "^2.0",
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^5.2",
    "ves/magento2-imageslider" :"dev-patch-1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
    "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/iMi-digital/magento2-theme-blank-sass"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/ihor-sviziev/imageslider"
    }
    ],
    "extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "auto-append-gitignore": "true"
    }
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

composer install
   composer require snowdog/theme-blank-sass=dev-master

Comment: Maybe this issue? https://github.com/AydinHassan/magento-core-composer-installer/issues/9

Comment: Could you show whole `composer.json` file of your forked theme?

Comment: You should change the name of the package to your custom, conflicting with a publicly available package isn't good practice at all.

Comment: You can see the composer.json on github imi digital... And I did it lots of times before with the same name...

Comment: Surprisingly, b/c your releases tagging methods doesn't follow any rules, everything works fine for me.

Comment: ;-) The problem arises when the branch is updated... I bumped the imi-develop branch (made a commit)... can you try a composer update now?

Comment: I don't have a develop version locally before, but updating between versions ( 0.110.1 -> develop or 0.10.1 to 0.110.1) works as expected.

Comment: I found out it happens also for other modules (splendidinternet/mage2-locale-de-de) -- something seems to be wrong with my magento installation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60621/discussion-between-alex-and-igloczek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "auto-append-gitignore": "true"
}
```

with

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

And it will work.

If you still need this option report an issue on M2 Github, b/c they are replacing `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer`, which seems to contain this feature, with own `magento/magento-composer-installer`.